# Altering a table's column type

Tags: google-bigquery

How am I supposed to alter a table's column type in BigQuery using a standard ALTER command?

```
alter table mytable 
alter column timestamp set data type date
```

The message I get is this:

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DATA TYPE is not supported at [2:1]

I have also tried standard SQL command (which doesn't work). The documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas

Doesn't mention anything about altering a column's type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August 3, 2021, Google BigQuery supports the exact syntax from the original question. See:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#August_03_2021

As an example:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [IF EXISTS] table_name
ALTER COLUMN [IF EXISTS] column_name SET DATA TYPE data_type
```

More details are available at:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_column_set_data_type_statement

Answer (score 1):

The recommended (or the only) way to change column type with Standard SQL is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE yourDataset.yourTable
AS SELECT * EXCEPT(col_a), CAST(col_a AS TIMESTAMP) AS col_a
```

Comment: Would the BQ team consider adding the ALTER TABLE syntax to maintain long term costs as well with the alter?

Comment: The first one was added last week: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#October_14_2020

 ==> ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN, and more are planned :)

Comment: I am aware of these changes, but it's only partial, it should been about much more. Also PIVOT is extremely important and useful. Make it a high priority.

Comment: I get this error: yourDataset.yourTable is not a supported object type at [1:19].

Comment: Oh, I missed "TABLE" before yourDataset.yourTable. Updated my answer

Comment: @Pentium10, both PIVOT and other ALTER TABLE are planned.